# If probability mass function $f(x)=\frac{c\cdot \lambda ^x}{x!}$ then find $c$ and $P(X=0)$ and $P(X >2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I cannot even begin to understand how can I find a $c$? The only thing that the function $f(x)$ reminds me of is Poisson distribution formula $\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}$. And then $c=e^{-\lambda}$. And from there $P(X=0) = c \text{ or } e^{-\lambda}.$ So, maybe I could find the second probability be subtracting from 1 the sum $$e^{-\lambda} + e^{-\lambda} \cdot \lambda + \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^2}{2} = c + \lambda \cdot c + \frac{c \cdot \lambda^2}{2}= 2c + 2\lambda c + \lambda^2 c. $$

So, the probability $P(X > 2) = 1 - (P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2))=1-2C-2\lambda c - \lambda^2 c$.

So, can someone tell me whether my solutions are correct or what is the mistakes I have made? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is correct. To prove that $c$ must be $e^{-\lambda}$ you have to use the fact that $\sum_{x \geq 0} P(X=x)=1$. This gives $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {c\lambda^{x}} {x!}=1$. But $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {\lambda^{x}} {x!}=e^{\lambda}$. This gives $c=e^{-\lambda}$.